# How to check if the Salesforce org is using "Salesforce Express Connect"?

Tags: setup, sales, service

I wanted to know if there is any way in Salesforce to check if "[Salesforce Express Connect](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/salesforce-express-connect/)" is being used.

Currently, I am not sure if we can check anywhere in Salesforce org to confirm if "Salesforce Express Connect" is being used.

Comment: This isn't actually managed within Salesforce, so no there isn't. You'll need to work with your network engineers to see if they are routing traffic to Salesforce via one of the providers.

Comment: Thanks @CallumMacErlich.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether your org is using Salesforce Express Connect you need to connect with your internal network team/telecom or your ISP provider. Salesforce express connect provides a direct private connection to your data center and is provided/managed by partner Telecom/ISP services.

Kindly review more details [here](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/salesforce-express-connect/).